# Increasing scroll back length of xterm

Tags: scrolling, xterm

I am logged in remotely to a CentOS 6.6 machine from a Mac with Yosemite running XQuartz 2.7.8.  When I run xterm on my CentOS machine, I'm can only scroll back about 1200 lines.  How do I increase this value?

Answer (score 9):

In the manual of xterm, you can find the description of the relevant option:

```
-sl number
This option specifies the number of lines  to  save  that  have
been scrolled  off the top of the screen.  This corresponds to the
saveLines resource.  The default is “64”.
```

So you can call

```
xterm -sl xxx
```

or create an alias

```
xterm='xterm -sl xxx'
```

or set   **saveLines** in your (or the global) Xresources file.

Comment: A concrete Xresources example: add the line `xterm*saveLines: 100000` to the `~/.Xresources` file.